# knockout multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Following code does multiple ajax calls. I'd like only one call actually.

```
        var update = function(){

        if(self.origin() && self.destination()){

            // AJAX CALL HERE
            $.get(something);

        }
    }


    self.origin.subscribe(function() {
        update(false);
    });

    self.destination.subscribe(function() {
        update(false);
    });

    self.origindatetime.subscribe(function() {
        update(true);
    });

    self.returndatetime.subscribe(function() {
        update(true);
    });
```

I tried [deferred updates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html). But no luck.

How can i avoid multiple ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of individually subscribing to each observable, consider using a computed observable and only make the ajax call when all your parameters are as desired (see **Example: Avoiding multiple Ajax requests** at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html).

The following is based on that example:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.origin = ko.observable();
    this.destination = ko.observable();
    ko.computed(function() {
        var params = { origin: this.origin(), destination: this.destination() };
            if (params.origin && params.destination) {
                $.get(something);
            }
    }, this).extend({ deferred: true });
}
```

The computed observable will evaluate when your view model is instantiated and then whenever origin or destination changes.

The **deferred** extension only assures that if you, for some reason, update both origin and destination at once (e.g. in another function) the computed observable will only be evaluated once.